# Как в Microsoft Word преобразовать ячейки последнего столбца таблицы в отдельные строки, следующие за строками ячеек

Tags: vba, ms-word, таблицы

Не могу найти в интерфейсе отдельного элемента под это дело. Стоит ли тогда пытаться преобразовать таблицу в текст и проводить все махинации оттуда? Не хочется случайно запороть таблицу 2500x4. Может, есть какой-то скрипт или плагин? Или я плохо ищу?

Comment: Гм... понять бы, что такое *отдельные строки, следующие за строками ячеек*. А если просто убрать линии границ последнего столбца - не оно?

Comment: Превратить 1[ABCD] 2[EFGH] в 1[ABC] 2[D] 3[EFG] 4[H]

Comment: Не, это только руками... *Не хочется случайно запороть таблицу 2500x4* Копии делать никогда не пробовал? пора бы и начать...

Comment: С каждой новой версией MS Office работать с этими продуктами становится все сложнее и сложнее.  Скоро будет снова актуальной строчка в резюме "Владею навыками работы с MS Office".  Ваша проблема может стать неактуальна с новой версией офиса.